# Steering problem

Tags: chevrolet, steering, impala, tie-rod

So on my 06 chevy impala,  i replaced the inner and outer tie rods myself on the front driver side. After i replaced it, the wheel is hard to turn, like if i had no power steering fluid, which i do, my power steering fluid is full, and there is shaking while i drive at any speed. I know i need to get an alignment thats where the shaking is coming from... but why is the wheel so hard to turn??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think you need to get the alignment done first before you can diagnose it. I'd *think* if you had too much toe out it might cause the situation you're talking about, but not sure.

Comment: Any unusual sounds? Everything was installed back the way it was (E.g. the tie rod end isn’t flipped)?